# What is a good equivalent to Perl lists in bash?

Tags: arrays, bash

In perl one would simply do the following to store and iterate over a list of names

```
my @fruit = (apple, orange, kiwi);
foreach (@fruit) {
        print $_;
}
```

What would the equivalent be in bash?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

bash (unlike POSIX sh) supports arrays:

```
fruits=(apple orange kiwi "dried mango")
for fruit in "${fruits[@]}"; do
  echo "${fruit}"
done
```

This has the advantage that array elements may contain spaces or other members of $IFS; as long as they were correctly inserted as separate elements, they are read out the same way.

Comment: I'm also seeing "dried" and "mango" printing as separate fruits here, using bash on Debian and Mac OS X. So this doesn't seem to protect against the IFS for me. :-(

Comment: emk, that's my bad -- I was testing on zsh, not bash; fixed it since.

Answer (score 11):

Like this:

```
FRUITS="apple orange kiwi"
for FRUIT in $FRUITS; do
  echo $FRUIT
done
```

Notice this won't work if there are spaces in the names of your fruits. In that case, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78592/what-is-a-good-equivalent-to-perl-lists-in-bash#78631) instead, which is slightly less portable but much more robust.

Comment: In Bash on Mac OS X, I appear to need either a semi-colon or line break before the 'do'.

Comment: Yes, you do need the semi-colon unless your "do" is on a new line. Also, $IFS must contain a space for this to work.

Comment: depending on IFS during iteration (rather than just assignment) is bad juju, making this answer suboptimal. Granted, mine did too -- I was testing on zsh, fixed for bash since.

Comment: This is buggy. See what happens if you have `*` as a fruit name -- instead of being literal, it's expanded as a glob, so you have files in your current directory showing up as fruits.

Answer (score 6):

Now that the answer I like has been accepted as the correct answer, I'll now move into another topic: how to use `IFS` for personal gain. :-P

```
fruits="apple,orange,kiwifruit,dried mango"
(IFS=,
 for fruit in $fruits; do
     echo "$fruit"
 done)
```

I've put the code in brackets so that the `IFS` change is isolated into its own subprocess; thus at the end of the bracketed section, `IFS` is reverted back to its old value. :-)

Comment: When I try `fruits=(apple orange "kiwi fruit")`, bash splits "kiwi" and "fruit" into separate entities during the loop. As long as you for/in, you'll get burned by the IFS. But `echo ${fruits[2]}` does the right thing, which is nice.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/78592/what-is-a-good-equivalent-to-perl-lists-in-bash#78631 for a version of this code which works.

Answer (score 4):

```
for i in apple orange kiwi
do
  echo $i
done
```

Comment: `echo "$i"` within the loop -- without the quotes, this does glob expansion and IFS splitting on the elements, making `foo   bar` the same as `foo bar` and making `*.txt` echo all the matching files in the current directory rather than emitting a literal `*.txt`.